# jQuery hide() targeting <p> element hides background of entire parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide

I have a simple blog page - a list of posts that each consist of a title and contents. When the page loads I want all posts' contents hidden until their titles are clicked. The following code accomplishes this but with an unwanted side effect - the on-page-load hide() function that hides each post's content also hides the background of the containing (id="content") div:

**Relevant JavaScripts**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".blog_post p").hide();

    //BLOG CONTENT ANIMATION
    $('.blog_post').click(function() {
        $(this).find('p').slideToggle(130);
    });      
});
```

**Summary of blog page**:

```
<section class="grid_7">
<div id="content">

    <div class="blog_post">

        <div class="blog_head">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </div>

        <p>Contents</p>

    </div>

</div>
</section>
```

**Relevant CSS**:

```
section { 
    border: 1px solid white;
}

#content {
    margin: 20px;
    background-image:url('../images/content_background.jpg');
}
```

When the page loads the list of titles displays without the #content parent div's background. However when I click on a post's title the #content div's background shows up behind all posts up to and including that one.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Well-defined question. Not immediately seeing anything than the below, can you make it happen in isolation, perhaps in an example on http://jsbin.com or http:/jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Hi, David. I'm not sure what you mean. The jQuery code hides the `<p>` elements initially and toggles show/hide with a sliding animation on them on clicking div elements with `.blog_post` class. If the background of #content is affected, either there's some other JavaScript performing some action on it or some CSS positioning the background image differently. I don't see how the current code could change background for #content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sound like you have some CSS that applies to the blog_head elements, that makes them float, for example:

```
.blog_post { float: left; }
```

In that case, the reason that the background doesn't show up is that the height of the content div is zero. A floating element doesn't affect the size of its parent, and when the content div only contains the headers, the height becomes zero. The background is still there, but there is no area where it's visible.

Add an overflow to the content div, that will make it contain its children:

```
#content { overflow: hidden; }
```

Note that this will not hide anything as long as you don't specify a size for the content element, it will just change how it's rendered so that it will become a container for its children.

Comment: Yeah, basically the lines I was thinking along as well. Neat trick with the `overflow: hidden` and float elements.

Comment: +1 for the amazing explanation.  I can say I learnt one more thing today!

Comment: Thanks! I had `float: left` applied to `.blog_post h2`, getting rid of that fixed it right up.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a stab in the dark: Your `#content` `div` will, of course, be a lot shorter as the blog posts aren't there, basically consisting just of the `div`s with the titles. Perhaps that's the problem.

Does the image have a blank (or subtle) bit at the top or something, so that it's only apparent that it's there when there's more content in the `#content` `div` (e.g., when it's taller)? Or is there some other reason you can see that when `#content` is really short, you wouldn't see the background on the part of it that's there? (You can use the debugging tools in most modern browsers to see what the dimensions of the `#content` div are when the paragraphs are hidden; or slap a border on it temporarily, but tools these days are pretty good.)

Basically, since the jQuery doesn't, of course, actually hide the background, it must be a side-effect of the paragraphs being hidden — because of the effect that has on the dimensions of the `#content` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me:

HTML:

```
    <div class="blog_post">

        <div class="blog_head">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </div>

        <p>Contents</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
section { 
    border: 1px solid white;
}

#content {
    margin: 20px;
    background-image:url('http://bluebackground.com/__oneclick_uploads/2008/04/blue_background_03.jpg');
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".blog_post p").hide();

    //BLOG CONTENT ANIMATION
    $('.blog_post').click(function() {
        $(this).find('p').slideToggle(130);
    });      
});
```

Check it live here: [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mANpQ/)